# How to embed a portlet in Asset Publisher?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I want to embed a portlet in an Asset Publisher in Liferay 6.2.
I did this:

```
<#assign siteMapPortletId = "85" />
<#assign PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil = staticUtil["com.liferay.portlet.PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil"] />
<#assign portletSetupFooter = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getLayoutPortletSetup(layout, siteMapPortletId) />
<#if portletSetupFooter.getValue("portletSetupShowBorders", "") != "false">
    <#assign myPreferences = portletSetupFooter.setValue("portletSetupShowBorders", "false") />
</#if>
<#assign myPreferences = portletSetupFooter.setValue("rootLayoutUuid", getPageID("Pages")) />
<#assign myPreferences = portletSetupFooter.setValue("displayStyle", getTemplateID("Sitemap")) />
<#assign myPreferences = portletSetupFooter.store() />

<#assign liferay_portlet = taglibLiferayHash["/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld"] />
<@liferay_portlet["runtime"]
    defaultPreferences=myPreferences
    portletName=siteMapPortletId
/>
```

but I get this error:

> liferay_portlet["runtime"] not found.

Comment: Try this <#assign liferay_portlet = taglibLiferayHash["/META-INF/liferay-portlet.tld"] /> and let me know....

Comment: why are you embedding portlets in an asset publisher ? ..